# Deleted all mail and folders as well as trash

Tags: gmail

I was on my iPhone 6s in my Gmail app and somehow deleted my All Mail folder.  This deleted all of my folders, inbox, sent, and drafts along with my trash and junk mail.  It wiped everything clean.  I have emails saved from 10 years prior.  I need to recover everything.  It never asked me to permanently delete.  It was a simple accident that I had no clue would delete everything.

Comment: What do you have when you visit gmail.com?

Answer (score 1):

From
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78353?hl=en:

> If you've deleted a message by choosing Delete Forever, you won’t be able to get the message back.
>
> If your messages are permanently deleted because someone got into your account without your consent, you can ask us to see whether we can recover your messages. To do this, do both of the following steps:
>
> 1. [Complete this process to secure your account.](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/50270)
> 2. [File a report.](https://support.google.com/mail/contact/missingemails)